# MySQL Finding the next row value by ID

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id    month     status
1   1997-11-01    A
1   2015-08-01    B
2   2010-01-01    A
2   2010-02-01    B
2   2012-10-01    C
```

That I would like to format to be:

```
id    month      lead_month    status
 1  1997-11-01   2015-08-01      A
 1  2015-08-01     NOW()         B
 2  2010-01-01   2010-02-01      A
 2  2010-02-01   2012-10-01      B
 2  2012-10-01     NOW()         C
```

MySQL is new to me, and I have trouble wrapping my head around variables. I would prefer to use a simple `LEAD()` with a `PARTITION` but unfortunately, I can't.

Here's my attempt, that doesn't work:

```
SET @lead = '1995-01-01'; --abitrary floor

select id, month, status, @lead, @lead:=month from table
```

The output looks like this, which also doesn't check if the id's from row to row are the same:

```
id    month      lead_month  status
 1  1997-11-01   1995-01-01    A
 1  2015-08-01   1997-11-01    B
 2  2010-01-01   2015-08-01    A
 2  2010-02-01   2010-01-01    B
 2  2012-10-01   2010-02-01    C
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't muck around with variables in MySQL. That sort of logic would better reside in whatever language you are using for your application. This, however can be done in SQL.

My first instinct is simply to save that data in an extra column. Don't worry about the size of the db–there aren't enough months in the universe to become a problem.

There is also something wrong with your ids: these should almost always be primary keys, i. e. unique.

If you insist on your scheme, you can use a join. Assuming consecutive unique ids:

`SELECT a.id, a.month, b.month AS lead_month, status FROM table AS a LEFT JOIN table AS b WHERE a.id - 1 = b.id;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.month
        from t t2
        where t.id = t2.id
        order by t2.month desc
        limit 1
       ) as next_month
from t;
```

If you want to replace the value for the last month for each id, then you can use `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce((select t2.month
                 from t t2
                 where t.id = t2.id
                 order by t2.month desc
                 limit 1
                ), now()) as next_month
from t;
```